# Locust or Jmeter for testing dashboard drill down reports

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, locust

I am trying to weigh in on open source tools like Jmeter or locust for testing dashboard charts and reports. I have tested the Http URL with Jmeter but how can we test the charts or graphs or reports that are embedded in a HTML page? Is there an option in JMeter or Locust or any other tool?

Basically for dashboards, HTML page loads faster but the chart loading and drill down takes time, which i think is the real key indicator of performance of a dashboard.

Appreciate your help.

Arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the load testing tools will execute client-side JavaScript and my expectation is that your charts are being loaded and "drilled down" (whatever it means) using [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) technology.

You can still execute the calls for the charts data in browser-like manner, for JMeter you can use [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/) for this, for Locust you will have to code it yourself, however this way you will not able to measure [rendering performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance) as this is something what browsers do.

So if you want to load test the backend - whatever tool should be capable of doing this, just make sure to produce the same network pattern like real browser do.

For the frontend performance assessment you will need a real browser, for example JMeter can be integrated with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) via [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/) and for Locust you can write the code which will kick off and orchestrate browser(s) using [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) module